# In JavaScript what is this method called where you might define a variable or property as such variable_name$ref

Tags: javascript

I am seeing it crop up more and more in code I am going through on a new project (can't share due to contractual reasons) where Ill see something like:

```
{
 prop1: value$ref,
 $prop2: null
}
```

I have see `${prop3}` before, but never an example without the brackets. Can anyone provide direction as to what the method is, or the operator is or whatever the case?

Comment: It's not a special operator or anything, it's just a plain property or variable name - that's really all there is to it

Comment: Its really that simple? lol! so basically if I did `my$varName` thats a valid variable, that I'd access the same way as I would `myvarName` had I done it without the dollar sign?

Comment: Yes.... nothing more to it

Comment: It's possible that it is being used as a decorator within your codebase specifically to signify something. Similar to the way that `_prop` often signifies a private property. In which case your question is probably better directed to the people who own it.